# Как вставить текстовое поле в TableViewController, чтобы оно было в самом низу?

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть TableViewController, и мне нужно, чтобы в самом низу экрана было текстовое поле для ввода. Т.е. это текстовое поле должно всегда оставаться внизу экрана при прокрутке таблицы. В таблице будут выводиться комментарии. А текстовое поле нужно для ввода своего комментария.

Проблема в том, что если в сториборде я перетягиваю TextField на контроллер таблицы, то он добавляется прямо под ячейку. Я не могу его привязать к нижней части экрана.

Или TableViewController не подойдёт для моей задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, в Вашем случае более удобным и гибким вариантом будет использование контейнеров:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И располагаете как Вам удобно в `Storyboard`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем понял как его использовать. У меня не получается так как у вас на картинке. Я перетягиваю Container View на таблицу, но контейнер всё равно закрепляется под ячейкой и я не могу его вниз переместить.

Comment: У меня так не получается. Container View если я перетаскиваю в сториборд на пустое место, то он не остаётся там. Если же я View Controller создаю и кидаю в него контейнер, а потом а этот контейнер пытаюсь кинуть Table View Controller, то на этот раз контроллер таблицы не хочет там размещаться.

Comment: Ну я уже нашёл другое решение. Я использую UITableView вместо контроллера.